# Disallow "contributors" to edit their own posts once they've been set to "Pending Review"

Tags: customization, user-roles

My question is exactly what is in the title: how can I disallow "contributors" to edit their own posts once they've been set to "Pending Review"? I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking if the post author is a contributor and post status is pending before the post is saved.

Before the post is saved:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'disallow_edit_pending_3748', 99, 2 );

function disallow_edit_pending_3748( $post_data, $post_array ){

    if( 'pending' == $post_data['post_status'] && current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ){

        // there's no other way to do this.
        // Nothing can stop the post from saving and still make sense to the user, except this.
        wp_redirect(add_query_arg( 'message', 999, get_edit_post_link( $post_array['ID'], 'url' )));
        exit;   
    }

    return $post_data;
}
```

The add_query_arg to add message=999 is optional. You could just do `wp_redirect(get_edit_post_link( $post_arr['ID'], 'url' ));`

However, adding that extra parameter can let you show a message. I'm hooking into WordPress's own message display.

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'add_custom_message_3748' );

function add_custom_message_3748( $messages ){
    $messages['post'][999] = "No, you can't do this!";
        return $messages;
}
```

The problem with this is that it will always be the update (green color) type. You can get creative and add admin notices using other ways.